# row 2 and row 1 difference

Tags: matlab

I have one column matrix with n rows of postitive and negative values . I want difference between row 2 and row 1 , row 3 and row 2 and so on. I should need the difference in a single column

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any ideas? This is a pretty basic question. A look around on SO will give you plenty of answers.

Comment: Try typing `help diff` in the Matlab command window.

Answer (score -2):

How do you want to measure the difference?
You cannot get all those differences in one single column without using a suitable norm, try "help norm"

```
[n,m]= size(A);
d=zeros(1,n)
for k= 1:n-1
    d(k) = norm(A(k,:))-norm(A(k+1,:));
end
```

The output is stored in the column-vector d.

Comment: -1: not quite...the OP asked for `r2-r1`, `r3-r2`, `r4-r3`, etc.